# Boardgame with dynamically created grid and a control inside to use drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

For school I have to create a boardgame of my choice. I chose a simple boardgame where you have to combine blocks of different colors in a way to gain most points out of it. You can have 2 to 4 players.

Until now I build a WPF application with MVVM and PRISM. The user is pressing a button to decide the amount of players and based on that I want to create a grid dynamically in XAML (because of MVVM and no code-behind) with sizes of 6x6, 7x7 and 8x8. In each cell there need to be a control (I don't know which one) which can hold a visual block.

My idea is to create that grid, put a ListBox in each cell, allow just one item for the ListBox and drag and drop a Rectangle on it.

For the dynamically created grid I read about using ItemsControl to build it up. Here a short code example, which isn't working:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GameBoard}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Row="{Binding Path=Rows}" Column="{Binding Path=Columns}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="20"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Inside I could place a ListBox to hold that block I was talking about. For my understanding I need to have a property bound to every single cell/ListBox to actually hold it and work with it in code.

There is plenty of stuff on the internet, but I couldn't wire it together to get it working. Do you have a point to start for me?

Comment: Having a ListBox in each grid cells seems odd, and the Grid should be in an `ItemsPanelTemplate` used for the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` property. Besides that, when this is a school project, you should probably ask your teacher to give you a starting point.

Comment: What else should I use instead of a ListBox? Not quite sure how to handle it. Yes I should ask him. I just started on my own to be a bit ahead of time. Will just see him again in two weeks.

Comment: You can use any UIElement or ContentElement as drop target, probably a most simple container like a Border. Take a look at [Drag and Drop Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I'd say it should contain a ContentControl (which I like to think of as an ItemsControl for a single item).